# Python - функция переписывает глобальную переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имею глобальную переменную (список):

```
game_matrix = ['7','8','9',],['4','5','6',],['1','2','3',]
```

а также функцию, которая должна брать из нее все сведения и загружать в похожий список, заменяя некоторые элементы. Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, что функция вносит изменения в глобальную переменную и очень смущает два факта:

1. функции не должны так делать
2. та часть кода, после выполнения которой данная переменная перезаписывается, не говорит явно, что нужно что-то в нее записать.

```
    index=0
    games = []
    for row in game_matrix:
        games.append(row)
    
    print (games)
    print (game_matrix)
    
    for row in games:
        if row[0] != 'o' and row[0] != 'x':
            games[index][0]=None
        if row[1] != 'o' and row[0] != 'x':
            games[index][1]=None
        if row[2] != 'o' and row[0] != 'x':
            games[index][2]=None
        index+=1
    
    print (games)
    print (game_matrix)
```

первая пара print в терминале дает:

```
    [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['o', '2', '3']]
    (['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['o', '2', '3'])
```

список и кортеж с нужными данными ([2][0]) изменяется еще до вызова функции, с этим проблем нет, но вот вторая партия print выводит уже странный результат:

```
    [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, 'o']]
    ([None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, 'o'])
```

собственно возникает вопрос почему цикл for .. in .. при переборе элементов взял и переписал game_matrix дав пустое значение?

Comment: `games.append(row)` - вот здесь вы добавляете в game **те же самые** списки, которые находятся внутри game_matrix, и любое изменение в списках из games будет видно в списках из game_matrix, потому что это одни и те же списки

Comment: в таком случае как редактировать копию списка, чтобы это не влияло на основной? Основной в кортеж изменить не получится, т.к. далее по коду буду вносить в него изменения, основываясь на результатах полученных от копии (games).

Comment: Да, @andreymal прав. Вы не копируете **game_matrix** в **games**, а связываете их. Тем самым при изменении **game_matrix** соответственно меняется и **games**.

Comment: Вы должны использовать: **games = [row.copy() for row in game_matrix]** при назначении массива и передаче значений из game_matrix

Comment: Все верно. Если добавлять через перебор не вложенные списки, а формировать новый и в него уже значения помещать, то это решит проблему. Впрочем через .copy() из ответа Xander получается намного приятнее и также решает проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ваша проблема в том, что вот в этом коде

```
games = []
    for row in game_matrix:
        games.append(row)
```

вы ожидаете, что у вас создастся копия матрицы, не связанная с оригиналом.

Однако надо понимать, что `games.append(row)` добавляет в новую матрицу *ту же саму строчку*, а не её копию. То есть теперь у вас есть *другая* матрица, но состоящая из трёх *тех же самых строчек*.

*(Если из других языков вы знакомы с понятием ссылки, то можно сказать, что строчка вставляется в новую матрицу по ссылке, а не по значению.)*

Для того, чтобы получить отдельную матрицу, никак не связанную с изначальной, нужно явно брать копию строки:

```
games = []
    for row in game_matrix:
        games.append(row.copy())  # Вот так вот
```

Comment: да, это решает проблему, как и помещение значений вложенных списков отдельно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Предложу ещё один вариант полного копирования массива: функция deepcopy модуля copy.
Копирование массива в данном случае будет выглядеть так:

```
from copy import deepcopy
games = deepcopy(game_matrix)
```

Comment: по факту тоже самое получается, так же в две строчки, не считая объявления переменной